# Oracle Custom sorting is not working

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have an issue while sorting a column in a custom order in Oracle.

I need a particular row in the column to come first and then the remaining items should come down below in the alphabetic order. The column has a data starting with alphabets, numbers and special characters.. whenever i try to sort the column by ASC it is returning me starting with Special characters first following by number and then alphabets.

Eg result Set

```
ACCOUNT_NAME
-------------
First Row
Second Row
Third Row
Fourth Row
Fifth Row
$Specialchar Row
4Number Row
Alpha Row
```

Expected result in the below order

```
ACCOUNT_NAME
-------------
First Row
Alpha Row
Fifth Row
Fourth Row
Second Row
Third Row
4Number Row
$Specialchar Row
```

I have tried executing the below query but it doesn't seems to be work

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME   FROM ACCOUNT
   ORDER BY decode(ACCOUNT_NAME,'First Row',1),
    regexp_substr(UPPER(ACCOUNT_NAME), '^[a-zA-Z]') ASC;
```

Comment: Why should the "first row come as first? Is it an hardcoded value?

Comment: Which bit of your attempted query doesn't work - what result do you get from that and why is it wrong? (Aside form the `First row`, you're only sorting by the first alphabetic character of the name, and even that regex is wrong; so 'Fourth' and 'Fifth' may be in any order; but not sure if that's what you mean...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to order this way:

1. an hardcoded values comes as first
2. strings starting with a letter, in alphabetic order
3. the strings starting with a digit
4. then all other strings, based on the ASCII value

If so, you may use a case to build a value to use in the order:

```
/* sample data */
with example(ACCOUNT_NAME) as (
    select 'First Row' from dual union all
    select 'Second Row' from dual union all
    select 'Third Row' from dual union all
    select 'Fourth Row' from dual union all
    select 'Fifth Row' from dual union all
    select '$Specialchar Row' from dual union all
    select '4Number Row' from dual union all
    select 'Alpha Row' from dual
)
/* query */
select *
from example
order by case
            when account_name = 'First Row' then 1
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[A-Za-z]') then 2
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[0-9]') then 3
            else 4
         end,
         account_name
```

How it works:

```
select case
            when account_name = 'First Row' then 1
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[A-Za-z]') then 2
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[0-9]') then 3
            else 4
         end as orderByValue,
         account_name
from example
order by case
            when account_name = 'First Row' then 1
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[A-Za-z]') then 2
            when regexp_like(account_name, '^[0-9]') then 3
            else 4
         end,
         account_name
```

gives:

```
ORDERBYVALUE ACCOUNT_NAME
------------ ----------------
           1 First Row
           2 Alpha Row
           2 Fifth Row
           2 Fourth Row
           2 Second Row
           2 Third Row
           3 4Number Row
           4 $Specialchar Row
```

Comment: @MUTHUKUMAR - [you might want to consider accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I think ASCII function will solve your issue. However it is easy to sort based on 1st char of the value.
E.g. 'AA' will come before '11',which will come before '$$'. However 'A$' will come before 'A4', which will come before 'AA' unless your extend the program to all characters. Extending this is quite tiresome.

So the code is as follows.

```
WITH data_set AS
     (SELECT '001' emp_id, 'aaa' emp_name, '005' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '005' emp_id, 'bbb' emp_name, '010' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '010' emp_id, 'ccc' emp_name, '050' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '020' emp_id, '4xy' emp_name, '050' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '050' emp_id, '$52' emp_name, '100' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '100' emp_id, '555' emp_name, '200' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '200' emp_id, '@$' emp_name, NULL mgr_id
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT   emp_name,
         CASE
            WHEN (ASCII (emp_name) BETWEEN 65 AND 90)
             OR (ASCII (emp_name) BETWEEN 97 AND 122)
               THEN 1
            WHEN ASCII (emp_name) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
               THEN 2
            ELSE 3
         END val
    FROM data_set
ORDER BY val;
```